# getting a garbage value in the place of rupee symbol in the csv file i wrote using python. please help me correct it

Tags: python

im trying to extract the flight details for a project. i was able to extract the information  but when im writing the extracted list, into the csv, im  facing issue with rupee symbol represented as a garbage value . image attached below and code used below

below is the code ,

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in flights_data:
        row = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in row]
        writer.writerows([row])
f.close()
```

output file looked like this

[image: output file]

Comment: Which program do you use to view the CSV file you have created?

Comment: Please post a relevant of the input data here.

Comment: Microsoft excel

Comment: Don't `.encode('utf-8')`, just pass `encoding='utf-8'` to `open()`. Further, look at the resulting file in a hex editor to see how the bytes are actually encoded and whether they correspond to the expected UTF-8 encoding of the character. If that's all working, then it's probably Excel notoriously failing at reading UTF-8 CSVs again.

Comment: The trailing `f.close()` is superfluous BTW, that's already handled by the `with` block.

Comment: I tried adding encoding=utf-8 to open, but that simply gave me a error asking me to remove that argument

Comment: Wat? What's the exact error message? Have you tried any of the other things I recommended?

Comment: it worked with encoding , thanks all

Comment: i used python 2.7 venv, when i changed to 3.7 it worked with adding utf-8